# How would I perform the following SQL search?

Tags: sql

Assume the following schema

```
user_id, tournament_id, round
```

How would I perform a search to find users in tournament_id=26, round=8 but not in tournament_id=26, round=7 i.e.

user has one row for tournament_id=26, round=8

zero rows for tournament_id=26, round=7

I've tried doing

```
where user_id not in (select ... where tournament_id=26 and round=7)
```

but it is very slow

Comment: Couple of things: Is this your only table? What is your exact query? Have you added any indexes?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are looking for. It might be interpreted as if you are looking for rows in your table where the 26,8 combination exist, or rows where the only combination for tournament 26 is round 8, meaning you need an entry for that combination and there should be no rows for 26,<anything but 8>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tournaments
WHERE tournament_id = 26
  AND [round] = 8

EXCEPT

SELECT user_id
FROM tournaments
WHERE tournament_id = 26
  AND [round] = 7
```

Or using an intermediate table:

```
SELECT user_id, [round]
INTO tournament26
FROM tournaments
WHERE torunament_id = 26;

SELECT user_id
FROM tournament26
WHERE [round] = 8

EXCEPT

SELECT user_id
FROM tournament26
WHERE [round] = 7
```

In SQL Server you can use a CTE instead of the intermediate table:

```
WITH tournament26 AS (
  SELECT user_id, [round]
  FROM tournaments
  WHERE tournament_id = 26
)
SELECT user_id
FROM tournament26
WHERE [round] = 8

EXCEPT

SELECT user_id
FROM tournament26
WHERE [round] = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
[user_id] INT, 
tournament_id INT, 
[round] INT
)

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT 1, 26, 8
UNION SELECT 1, 26, 7
UNION SELECT 2, 26, 7
UNION SELECT 3, 26, 7
UNION SELECT 4, 26, 8
UNION SELECT 4, 25, 8
UNION SELECT 4, 25, 7

SELECT user_id, tournament_id, MAX(round), COUNT(1)
FROM   #t
WHERE  tournament_id=26
GROUP BY user_id, tournament_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 AND MAX(round) = 8
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have a users table as well?

Try this:

```
select * from users u
join tournament t on t.user_id = u.id
where t.tournament_id=26 and t.round=8
```